# Import from Access to Excel not working correctly

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

My problem involves the importing of data from a 2 separate Access queries in the same database into 2 different Excel workbooks.

One query works fine, connects to the datasource...great..

But the second query does not work correctly, it only pulls the column headers from the query and not the details.

Firstly, here is the first query that works perfectly fine.

[Query 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak8vu.jpg) 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak8vu.jpg]

The above query works fine when I connect to it using the "External Source" option in Excel, pulls data, can refresh it and everything.

This is the second query

[Query 2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBNSS.jpg)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBNSS.jpg]

This query does not work correctly, well, it works fine when you run it inside the database, but as soon as you try and connect to it like the first query, all it does it bring up the column headings but none of the data.

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you change the criterion on `dbo_Queue.Name` from `Like "uk*"` to `ALike "uk%"`?

Comment: @HansUp That seems to have done the trick, can you clarify why that would of made a difference? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the criterion on `dbo_Queue.Name` from `Like "uk*"` to `ALike "uk%"`

You didn't say how you're connecting to Access from Excel.  Queries run from ADO/OleDb connections require ANSI wild card characters for `Like` pattern-matching: `%` and `_` instead of `*` and `?`

But my suggestion was to use `ALike` instead of `Like` because `ALike` signals the db engine to always expect ANSI wildcards regardless of where and how the query is run.  Therefore the query should return the same result set when run from Excel as it does when run from within an Access session.

Comment: My apologies for not including what the type of connection was, bit beyond my knowledge unfortunaely! I am learning! After a little bit of investigation it would be a OleDB connection which makes more sense now.

Many thanks for your quick response, it has been very helpful. I've got the answer I need, it may be simple for others but it's helped me greatly!!